# Ec2 c4.large not responding

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, performance, performance-monitoring, network-monitoring

I have this ec2 c4.large machine where I'm hosting a video player, for iframe embed purposes in favor of other sites. I'm posting aws stats from aws admin interface:
[image]

As you can see, the cpu is barelly 10% of usage, disk I/O is 0%, network in is around 7 500 000 bytes, and network out is around 50 000 000 bytes. Do you think the problem comes from the network?

I'm posting also the **htop** (ubuntu) command results 
[image]

As you can see, ram workload is around 800mb, most of it is used by cache (I'm using mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb package for managing cache in apache). I'm really confused here where the problem comes from, the server is very slow (I have to wait 40s before I get a response, but when the traffic is low, it's instantaneous like 1s). Do you think it could be a database problem? but the cpu is literally idle.

I'm posting also the **speedometer** results from the inside of ubuntu:
the command is: **speedometer -l  -r eth0 -t eth0 -m $(( 1024 * 1024 * 3 / 2 ))**
[image]

Is it normal that network OUT stats shown by **speedometer** is far less than aws's results?  speedometer: ~ 2Mb & aws: 50Mb

I'm posting also the **nmon** command for disk monitoring (inside ubuntu)

[image]

As you can see it doesn't exceed 350kb during the read operations

So I can't see what could cause this latency problem, is there any thing else that I have to check?

I'm adding as an attachement the google analytics stats (active users)
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Are you hitting a database at all?

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, yeah I'm using a mysql database, do you think the problem could be database overloaded? but viewing the graphes show that cpu is not overloaded

Comment: I'd be looking at your MySQL slow query log, and do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` against the database server during one of these slowdowns.

Comment: mmm.. yeah that's a good debuging solution, can you help me with the command line for this task